# Beginning and ending a block of CSS code

Tags: css

When I use styling CSS as in the following:

```
#test p{/*css code here*/}
#test span{/*css code here*/}
#test p.one{/*css code here*/}
#test span.test{/*css code here*/}
```

Then select the div with id `#test` each time would be easier, as in the following:

```
begin #test
p{/*css code here*/}
span{/*css code here*/}
p.one{/*css code here*/}
span.test{/*css code here*/}
end #test
```

Is this good practice for CSS styling? if so, I hope this would be added into future versions of CSS.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use a dynamic CSS language such as LESS: http://lesscss.org/‎ OR Sass http://sass-lang.com/ as @steveax points out

Comment: Or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting suggestion, but I would rather stick to the original. I know it might be too much to type `#test` 100 times, but in the `css`, people might find it hard to see the `begin` and `end` keywords.

Especially when you have other `p, span`, and the same thing inside the begin and end might look confusing.

This is just an opinion of course...

Answer (score 0):

In csslint validation you generally are not allowed to use ids. I believe the reason for that would be reusability problem. I think beginning and ending so specifically also poses a problem to css code reusability. I prefer using element properties that can be reused by many elements.

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP (which is suggesting a "scope" mechanism)?

Comment: Good response. Csslint was also written by Nicole Sullivan who was the early pioneer behind OOCSS. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Do not over scope. I am sure the community here might disagree,

1. Forget that IDs ever existed (prepares to be lynched)
2. Avoid scoping a class to an element (p.one should be written as /* p */.one or .one)

Please look at this:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/

https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss-accessibility-guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Nested selectors is currently **not** a good CSS practice, because it's not valid CSS and it doesn't work.

CSS compilers (such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/)) allow more dynamic CSS development by adding functionality like nesting, variables and loops/logic.  CSS compilers are to CSS as PHP is to HTML.

There are [some](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/) [who](http://meiert.com/en/blog/20081021/exercise-for-emerging-css-experts/) [would](http://twobanjos.com/blog/2011/06/why-well-stop-using-id-in-our-stylesheets/) advocate for avoiding `id`s in any CSS styling.  You'll have to consider the arguments carefully and decide whether that practice makes any sense for your *implementation*.

If you wish to influence upcoming CSS specifications and recommendations, you can work with the [W3C CSS WG](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html).